# .NET: class definition explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I understand basic inheritance and I understand the basics of generics.

But I do NOT understand this class definition:

```
public class ExportController : AbstractFeedController<IExportFeed>
```

The `ExportController` inherits  `AbstractFeedController`...

but, what does the `<IExportFeed>` do/mean? Is it something to do with generics?

Comment: It'll all become very clear once you look up the definition of `AbstractFeedController<T>`.

Comment: And because there are about ten thousand potential duplicates, I can't find one that properly explains this, so feel free to answer this as well and fragment the information on this site even more. All of this is explained in the first paragraphs of the first Google hit for "C# inheriting from generic base class" anyway: [MSDN: Generic Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a generic definition. In short, `AbstractFeedController` defines a generic implementation that can be applied to various Types including `IExportFeed` in your case.

Look at the definition of the class `AbstractFeedController`, you will likely see something like

```
class AbstractFeedController<T>{ ...
```

In the class you will then see the Type `T` used multiple times. Whenever you see this `T`, you can swap it in your mind with any Type you think can apply.

In the class definition, you might also see a `where T : ...`. This is a condition on the Type `T`, limiting the kind of Types the class can use.

Read [this MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 4):

[An Introduction to C# Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) chapter [Inheritance and Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic6):

> When deriving from a generic base class, you must provide a type argument instead of the base-class's generic type parameter:

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{...}
public class SubClass : BaseClass<int>
{...}
```

> If the subclass is generic, instead of a concrete type argument, you can use the subclass generic type parameter as the specified type for the generic base class:

```
public class SubClass<T> : BaseClass<T> 
{...}
```

This means that your class `ExportController` is no longer generic and is derived from class `AbstractFeedController<IExportFeed>`.

Answer (score 2):

In plain english it means that `ExportController` is deriving from a closed generic typed class `AbstractFeedController<IExportFeed>`. `AbstractFeedController` class has some of the methods, properties, fields, indexers etc whose types or return types or parameter types could be of type `IExportFeed` .

So AbstractFeedController class may look like this

```
//This is a open type:
public class AbstractFeedController <T>
{
   T[] m_Items; 
   public void Feed(T item)
   {...}
   public T ReturnFeed()
   {...}
}
```

Now we close the type by intansiating a class with `IExportFeed` as generic type parameter

```
AbstractFeedController feedController = new AbstractFeedController<IExportFeed>();
```

So the class internally translates as follows:

```
//This is a closed type now:
public class AbstractFeedController <IExportFeed>
{
   IExportFeed[] m_Items;  //Indexer type of IExportFeed
   public void Feed(IExportFeed item) //A method accepting a parameter of type IExportFeed
   {...}
   public IExportFeed ReturnFeed() //A method returning type of IExportFeed
   {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the situation like

```
public class ExportController : IExportFeed
public class ImportController : IImportFeed
```

let's assume that in export case we have some operations common for all implementers of IExportFeed. So may move these operations into some base abstract class for IExportFeed hierarchy.
Same for IImportFeed.

But what if we have some common operations for both these hierarchies?
we can do something like

`public abstract class ImportExportController : IExportFeed, IImportFeed`

and inherit export or import classes from this one.

But this design breaks minimum couple of SOLID principles, and it's going to be a mess if you decide to add anoter feed interfaces

The solution is to move this common inter-hierarchy functionality into a generic(template)

```
public class ExportController : AbstractFeedController<IExportFeed>
public class ImportController : AbstractFeedController<IImportFeed>
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

The inherited class implicitly defines the type of the generic class.

So the inherited class is not generic anymore, and uses the base class for the provided type.

Comment: _"implicitly defines the type of the generic class"_ - yeah, no. Can you reword that? Keyword being "constructed generic type".